# Are these Mozilla-specific CSS styles doing anything?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, mozilla

I'm working with some CSS (from a Joomla template) like this:

```
div#logo {
    -moz-background-clip: border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;
    -moz-background-origin: padding;
    background: transparent url(../images/head.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    ...
}
```

I've looked up some of those `-moz-` properties and they seem to be assigned their default values, and if I turn them off in Firebug nothing happens visibly.

Would there be a reason to add them to a CSS file? Are they for an old version of Firefox perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what's happened is someone's set a `background` shortcut rule and then looked at the ‘computed style’ resulting from that shortcut rule in the DOM inspector. They've noticed that setting the style also sets Mozilla's `background-clip`, `-origin` and `-inline-policy` properties, and tried to reproduce these rules without understanding what they're for (namely a detail of Mozilla's CSS implementation, and potentially CSS3 in future).

Certainly changing `-moz-background-inline-policy` would only have any effect on elements that were `display: inline` (which `div` isn't by default), and changing the `clip`/`origin` properties around the border would only make any difference if the element actually had a border.

Get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that these properties don't need to be there. I'd suspect that they're included to ensure consistent rendering across different versions of Firefox. I guess the answer is, if you're seeing no difference from disabling them in the versions of Firefox you're interested in supporting, take them out.

Answer (score 0):

`background-clip` isn't supported on current Firefox builds AFAIK, so the author has probably put them in preempting a problem (though that would be odd as they are all set to the default anyway, and they haven't included the opera or webkit prefixes...)

`background-inline-policy` is default as `continuous` in all Firefoxes, and `background-origin` is default as `padding` in them all too.

I'd say pointless code for this one.

Answer (score -1):

> If I turn them off in Firebug nothing happens visibly.

I'm not sure on those particular attributes, but have you checked that the browser isn't using a cached style sheet?

Comment: Um...don't think you read my question. I'm asking if the `-moz` properties need to be there or not.

Comment: Yeah and you mentioned "If I turn them off in Firebug nothing happens visibly." I had a similar situation where clearing the cache solved that problem.